# I am trying to create word document from R Markdown. but the toc:TRUE option is throwing an error

Tags: r, r-markdown, tableofcontents

I am trying to create word document from R Markdown. but the toc:TRUE option is throwing an error which i couldnot understand. Can anyone please help me understand this. My pandoc version is :

```
> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘1.19.2.1’
```

My sample code:

````
---
title: "Energy Assessment Report"
output: 
  word_document:
     toc:yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

error:

```
Error in eval(parse(text = name)) : object 'toc' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... create_output_format -> create_output_format_function -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

Comment: "true" instead of "yes"

Comment: You just need a space I think: `toc: yes`. @Rob `yes` works fine in the the YAML header, you can use either `yes` or `true` interchangeably

Comment: space after : works perfectly.. Thank you very much Rob and Marius for your help.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering from comments.)

The YAML format is *extremely* whitespace-sensitive: `toc: yes` or `toc: true` will both work, but **there must be a space after the colon**.